# Angular JS form appears twice on page, how to deal with duplicate IDs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I an using ng-include to load a form onto the page (templates/form.html).

The user can also click a button which opens an Angular UI modal window, containing the same form loaded from the same template.

This is causing me problems because I am using `<label for="email">` for things like checkboxes and having the form on the page is causing duplicate element IDs (so clicking labels checks the box in both forms).

Is there a way to load the include then alter the names of the IDs in each using some kind of interpolation? Maybe something like `<input type="checkbox" id="{{instanceName}}-email">`

Or perhaps there is a better solution?

Comment: You can use `<label> <input /></label>`, If you include the input tag in the label tag, you don't need to use the 'for' attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you could have naming collision if the scope of the modal inherits from its parent.

So make sure that your modal has a completly new an independant scope and then change instanceName on controller initialization.